# how to use icon from ttf file using unicode

Tags: css, fonts, icons, truetype, glyphicons

I am currently using `<span class="icon-home2"></span>` to show icons in my CSS file:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'icomoon';
src:    url('fonts/icomoon.eot?4r9x8o');
src:    url('fonts/icomoon.eot?4r9x8o#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.ttf?4r9x8o') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.woff?4r9x8o') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.svg?4r9x8o#icomoon') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
/* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
font-family: 'icomoon' !important;
speak: none;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-variant: normal;
text-transform: none;
line-height: 1;

-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}



.icon-home:before {
content: "\e900";
}
```

Now I have a different requirement in which I need show the icons, with content in CSS, using unicode that is mapped here:

```
.icon-home:before {
    content: "\e900";
}
```

Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this?

Comment: unrelated to your problem, but related to modern web design work: stop using all those deprecated, abandoned, and redundant font formats. Use WOFF, use `eot` if you *have* to support IE8 and below, and leave it at that. WOFF is byte-for-byte equivalent to the ttf/otf source font, so if you already have WOFF, adding ttf/otf is pointless, `eot` was already deprecated but is now obsolete, as MS *officially* no longer supports IE8 and below, and `svg` hasn't been a real font format in years. Always simplify your problems: start by just using WOFF.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer: 
add in css file

```
[data-icon]:before {
  font-family: icomoon; /* BYO icon font, mapped smartly */
  content: attr(data-icon);
  speak: none; /* Not to be trusted, but hey. */
}
```

and access with

```
<i aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe908;"></i>
```

remember to append &#x before unicode of icons eg icon code is e001 then data-icon="&#xe001"